# Matlab dimension mismatch

Tags: matlab, for-loop

```
for n=1:1:20
    et1(:,n) = 0  
    for m=1:1:5

        et2(:,n) = (exp( t*(-n/tau) ).*( (t*(n/tau)).^(m*n-1) )/( factorial(m*n - 1) ))*(n);
        et1(:,n) =  (exp(t*(-n/tau)).*( (t*(n/tau)).^(m*n-1) )/( factorial(m*n - 1) ))*(n) + et1(:,n);   

    end    
end
```

I cant really figure out why is is showing this error. t is a vector of dimension 369.
et2 is working correctly and giving correct values. tau is a constant.

Comment: why are you `et1(:,n) = 0  ` is the first loop?

Comment: its basically et1(:,n) = et2(:,n) + et1(:,n) for m=1:1:5

Comment: so why do you need a for loop? just ` et1  = et2  + et1 `

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error from matlab because, as [natan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292464/natan) hinted you in his first comment, you did not initialize your variable **et1** (or may be you did, but with the wrong size). In your line:

> et1(:,n) = 0 ;

Matlab cannot know on how many lines it has to apply the instruction *(this Nth column of et1)=0*.

The simple way to solve this is to pre-initialize your variable before the *FOR* loop (and if you know the size in advance, *it is also good practice anyway*, matlab is faster this way). So before your double *for* loop, insert something like:

```
nColumn = 20 ;  
et1 = zeros( length(t) , nColumn ) ;
```

This way no more *Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch* error, and you can also get rid of your expression *et1(:,n) = 0 ;* in your loop because all elements of **et1** are initialized to 0 already.

Then on with your calculations. In your most inner loop, you calculate the expression for `et2` five times (for **`m`**=1 to 5), but every time you write the result in the same place (the Nth column of `et2`). As a result you only save the last calculation (for **`m`**=5) in your `et2` column. 
If you want to save the result of the expression for each of the five value of **`m`**, then you will have to add a dimension to your matrix. 
 However, if `et2` was only intended to be used temporarily to add its result for each value of **`m`** to the column of `et1`, then you can get rid of it altogether (or simply use a temporary column vector).

If I understood correctly your code and your intent, then the following code should work for you:

```
//% initialize your matrix
nColumn = 20 ;
et1         = zeros( length(t) , nColumn) ;
et2_tempCol = zeros( length(t) , 1 ) ;

//% Run the loop
for n=1:nColumn
    for m=1:1:5
        et2_tempCol(:) = (exp( t*(-n/tau) ).*( (t*(n/tau)).^(m*n-1) )/( factorial(m*n - 1) ))*(n) ;
        et1(:,n) = et2_tempCol + et1(:,n);   
    end    
end
```

Note that I only use the temporary variable `et2_tempCol` and the `(:)` index assignment to make sure that will will pass a *column* vector to `et1`.This can take care of any shape of your vector **`t`** (whether its a *line* or *column* vector). Otherwise Matlab may get angry and throw another *Matrix dimensions must agree* error at you.

If you control the dimension of your vector **`t`** (*line* or *column*) and do not need to save the result of `et2` at all, then you can get rid of it completely by using in your inner loop:

**if `t` is a *line* vector:**

```
et1(:,n) = ( (exp(t*(-n/tau)).*( (t*(n/tau)).^(m*n-1) )/( factorial(m*n - 1) ))*(n) ).' + et1(:,n);
```

**if `t` is a *column* vector:**

```
et1(:,n) = ( (exp(t*(-n/tau)).*( (t*(n/tau)).^(m*n-1) )/( factorial(m*n - 1) ))*(n) ) + et1(:,n);
```